# Firebase query from Android application download a lot of data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a query to Firebase from an Android app, the query is as follows:

Query 1

```
reference.orderByChild("started").equalTo(true)..addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            gameOnList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot gamesSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Game game = gamesSnapshot.getValue(Game.class);
                    if(game.isStarted()) gameOnList.add(game);
                }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

This query returns 5 results but consumption is 1.5 Mb as if it returns all the records. What can be happening?

I have done another test, with the following query does not occur that consumption of data:

Query 2

```
Reference.limitToLast (5) .addValueEventListener (new ValueEventListener () {            
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            gameOnList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot gamesSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Game game = gamesSnapshot.getValue(Game.class);
                    if(game.isStarted()) gameOnList.add(game);
                }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Also returns 5 records but in this case consumes only 10 kb.

How could I make the first query without this excessive consumption of data?

The database consulted has about 1800 records.

The structure of the database is this:

```
Game: 
          -KW_-cgwIPt5E8lzguds:
                               level1: array
                               level2: array
                               level3: array
                               level4: array
                               player1: String
                               player1Pts: int
                               player2: String
                               player2Pts: int
                               player1End: boolean
                               player2End: boolean
                               started: boolean
                               completed: boolean
          -KW_-cgwIPt5E8lztyd5:
                               level1: array
                               ....
```

Comment: How do you measure data consumption of each of these methods?

Comment: When you pick the data from the Firebase Database, do you really need all the details about every game? or maybe only that keys/another value?    https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#avoid_nesting_data

Comment: Do you have an index on the `started` child?

Comment: ishmaelMakitla I measure data consumption with a network counter in the android phone.

Comment: vzsg No, I haven't, I'll try to do the index, thanks

Comment: It was the index, the problem was solved, thanks vzsg

Answer (score 2):

To sum up the comments: if you build a query using the filtering operators `equalTo`, `startAt` or `endAt`, you should add an *index* to the security rules for the chosen child node.

Without them, the client is forced to perform the equivalent of a "full scan" – downloading *every single child*, but reporting only those that match the criteria.

There is a warning printed for this very reason for any non-conforming query to the application logs. Or if you tried to perform the same query using the REST API, it would be rejected immediately.